# Unable to get sorted records. Getting empty file

Tags: mainframe, jcl

I am trying to sort a file using DFSORT utility, the JCL is running successfully with code maxcc=00 but the output file I am getting is empty, please help me,

My input file

```
02AAP000000701050000190116200116012013173000  01R300118
03PC PIFIXSYS20111800FIX FOR 12LA UPDATE               
03PC PIFIXSYS20050700ORG DATE FIX                      
03PC PIFIXSYS1911270012AI LINE1 AND SORT FIX
```

I want only first line of my input to get in output file but getting empty file.
My JCL for sort

```
//STEP030  EXEC PGM=SORT                                      
//SORTIN    DD DISP=SHR,DSN=T.CAOS.PE8523.PIF.MSTEXT.EXPAND   
//*                                                           
//SORTOUT   DD DSN=T.CAOS.PE8523.PIFFIX.SORTED,               
//             DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),                       
//             STORCLAS=SCTSO,                                
//             MGMTCLAS=MCTSO,                                
//             RECFM=VB,LRECL=304,BLKSIZE=0,                  
//             SPACE=(CYL,(10,5),RLSE)                        
//SYSOUT    DD SYSOUT=*                                       
//SYSIN    DD    *                                            
  SORT FIELDS=COPY                                            
  INCLUDE COND=(1,2,CH,EQ,C'02')                              
/*
```

error log in spool

```
SYSIN :                                                                       
  SORT FIELDS=COPY                                                      008800
  INCLUDE COND=(1,2,CH,EQ,C'02')                                        008900
WER813I  INSTALLATION OPTIONS IN MFX LOAD LIBRARY WILL BE USED                
WER276B  SYSDIAG= 13300297, 21826883, 21826883, 21059935                      
WER164B  7,908K BYTES OF VIRTUAL STORAGE AVAILABLE, MAX REQUESTED,            
WER164B     0 BYTES RESERVE REQUESTED, 2,488K BYTES USED                      
WER146B  32K BYTES OF EMERGENCY SPACE ALLOCATED                               
WER108I  SORTIN   : RECFM=VB   ; LRECL=   304; BLKSIZE= 27998                 
WER073I  SORTIN   : DSNAME=T.CAOS.PE8523.PIF.MSTEXT.EXPAND                    
WER110I  SORTOUT  : RECFM=VB   ; LRECL=   304; BLKSIZE= 27998                 
WER074I  SORTOUT  : DSNAME=T.CAOS.PE8523.PIFFIX.SORTED                        
WER410B  5,856K BYTES OF VIRTUAL STORAGE AVAILABLE ABOVE THE 16-MEGABYTE LINE,
WER410B     0 BYTES RESERVE REQUESTED, 2,344K BYTES USED                      
WER055I  INSERT          0, DELETE         37                                 
WER211B  SYNCSMF  CALLED BY SYNCSORT; RC=0000                                 
WER449I  SYNCSORT GLOBAL DSM SUBSYSTEM ACTIVE                                 
WER416B  SORTIN   : EXCP'S=1,UNIT=3390,DEV=C679,CHP=(BCC1CDCED0D3,1),VOL=TALF0A
WER416B  SORTOUT  : EXCP'S=0,UNIT=3390,DEV=C49A,CHP=(BCC1CDCED0D3,1),VOL=TASF06
WER416B  TOTAL OF 1 EXCP'S ISSUED FOR COPYING                                 
WER054I  RCD IN         37, OUT          0                                    
WER169I  RELEASE 2.1 BATCH 0539 TPF LEVEL 3.0                                 
WER052I  END SYNCSORT - PE8523AP,STEP030,,DIAG=CE00,51C2,E2AC,006E,8652,68EB,26A8,2460,0100,0300
```

Comment: Please remove inappropriate tags! This is a ```sort``` question, ```mainframe```, and ```jcl``` tags are fine, but the question has nothing to do with neither ```cobol```, nor ```rexx```.

Comment: @phunsoft, sorry for adding rexx and cobol, I know it is not related to it but I thought cobol and rexx are used in mainframes, so people following cobol and rexx can help me, but no issues now, I have removed the rexx and cobol tags.

Comment: Actually the JCL tag is wrong as well as there is no error with the JCL but your sort control statements which are not JCL. There is also a SYNCSORT tag that you could use. And an alternative solution is to use STOPAFT=n where n is the number of records to process before stopping.

Comment: @NicC I don't understand your suggstion to use ```STOPAFT```.

Comment: "I want only first line of my input to get in output file"  therefor a simple copy operation with STOPAFT=1 will copy the first record only. Job done.

Comment: @NicC I didn't notice that fact :-( My bad. So, indeed, the STOPAFT=1 would be a more elegant solution.

Comment: @Siddhesh You start your question with "I'm trying to sort a file...", but you don't sort anything with ```SORT FIELDS=COPY". It is a very valid operation, don't get me wrong, but you sould be precise in describing what you want to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're sorting a `RECMF=VB` data set, so your first data byte in the records is in position 5. Adjust the `INCLUDE` statement accordingly:

`INCLUDE COND=(5,2,CH,EQ,C'02')`

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it is working fine now.